# Getting DropDownList values in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater

**ASPX PAGE:**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="GeneralRepeater" runat="server" 
 OnItemDataBound="GeneralRepeater_OnItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
      <td>
       DxPoc:
         <asp:DropDownList ID="GeneralDDL" DataTextField="DiagnosisCode" 
         DataValueField="DiagnosisCode" runat="server" />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
protected void GeneralRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender,
                                               RepeaterItemEventArgs e)


     {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
                e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("GeneralDDL");
                Diagnosis oDiagnosis = new Diagnosis();
                DataView dv = new DataView(oDiagnosis.GetDiagnosis());
                myDDL.DataSource = dv;
                myDDL.DataTextField = "DiagnosisCode";
                myDDL.DataValueField = "DiagnosisCode";
                myDDL.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

The given shown above is not working properly. During page load it nothing happens on the 
dropdownlist inside the repeater.

**QUESTIONS:**

a.) How I'll get the values of my `dropdownlist` with list of objects inside the `repeater`?

thanks!

Comment: You want to bind dropdown list, that is inside in repeater ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    BindRepeater();
}
```