# Dropdownlist inside a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How to start a dropdownlist with an empty values?

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get round this
problem, aside from creating a blank manager entry in the table, which
is obviously not ideal!

Many thanks!

**ASPX PAGE**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="GeneralRepeater" runat="server" 
 OnItemDataBound="GeneralRepeater_OnItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
      <td>
       DxPoc:
         <asp:DropDownList ID="GeneralDDL" DataTextField="DiagnosisCode" 
         DataValueField="DiagnosisCode" runat="server" />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
protected void GeneralRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender,
                                               RepeaterItemEventArgs e)


     {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
                e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("GeneralDDL");
                Diagnosis oDiagnosis = new Diagnosis();
                DataView dv = new DataView(oDiagnosis.GetDiagnosis());
                myDDL.DataSource = dv;
                myDDL.DataTextField = "DiagnosisCode";
                myDDL.DataValueField = "DiagnosisCode";
                myDDL.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

Comment: what's your problem ? you have posted the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039318/getting-dropdownlist-values-in-a-repeater

Comment: @Muhammad, im done on databind of dropdownlist inside of repeater. Now, I'm to start for every load page that my dropdownlist will have an empty fields and then a databind..

Answer (score 0):

You will want to insert code like this into your ItemDataBound function, after the DDL has been databound:

```
    ListItem LI = New ListItem("(empty item)", "0");
    myDDL.Items.Insert(0, LI);
    myDDL.SelectedValue = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

Alter your listitem by setting `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="GeneralDDL" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="DiagnosisCode" DataValueField="DiagnosisCode" 
        runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: hmmm.. i put asp:ListItem on my code.. its not working.. I think its not compatible inside of the repeater?

Comment: You need to set this AppendDataBoundItems="true" as well of your dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
    dropDownList.DataSource = AddHeaderItem
    (
        list.ToDictionary
            (instance => instance.Key.ToString(), instance => instance.Value), 
        true, 
        "Please Select an Item..."
    );


    // Add a header item to a Dictionary ..
    public static Dictionary<String, String> AddHeaderItem
        (Dictionary<String, String> items, Boolean addHeaderItem, 
           String headerItemText = "")
    {

        var headerItem = new Dictionary<String, String>();

        if (addHeaderItem)
        {
            headerItem["-1"] = headerItemText;
        }
        //else { }

        return headerItem.Concat(items).ToDictionary
             (item => item.Key, item => item.Value);

    }
```